# Return 200 HTTP code in a fire and forget API

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to create a public "fire&forget" API, which at present returns a `200 OK HTTP` code.

According to [WSO2 ESB documentation for 202 Accepted](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+12%3A+One-Way+Messaging+in+a+Fire-and-Forget+Mode+through+ESB), I have to set true in FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED property. 
However, I don't want to return 202, I want to return 200.

Is it possible to force return 200 in a "fire&forget" API using other property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set http status code :

```
<property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2"/>
```

generate an empty message :

```
<enrich>
    <source type="inline">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body/>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </source>
    <target type="envelope"/>
</enrich>
```

set message type to choose the appropriate message formatter (sample for soap12) :

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/soap+xml"/>
```

Send it back as if it was a response message :

```
<header name="To" action="remove"/>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
<send/>
```